# Understanding nested react routers

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So i started learning react few days ago and i eventually came to the topic of react router, i started to learn about nested routes, and couldn't wrap my head around it.

I have created a very simple use case, i have three components, named, App, `component2` and `component3`. In my `App.js` i display `component1`, and a route to `component2`, in `component2` i display `component2` with route to `component3`, and finally in `component3` only `component3`.

Here is how my `App.js` looks like:

```
export default function App() {
  function Component3() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component3</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  function Component2() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component2</h1>
        <Link to="/component3">goto nested level 2</Link>
        <hr />
        <Route path="/component3" component={Component3} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component1</h1>
      <Link to="/component2">goto nested level 1</Link>
      <hr />
      <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now at first, when i load the app, it loads component1, and link to component2, when i click that link to
component2, it loads component2, but when i click the link to component3 in component2 it dosen't load component3 also component2 vanished from the screen.

Now i researched a lot on stack overflow and other sites, i found how that this is because route named **/component3** is nowhere defined in app, hence this is the behavior.

So my question is that, i have clearly defined in component2 that, on route **/component3** please load **component3** then why it dosen't load that component3 but changes the route to **/component3** successfully. I can't understand the flow and how it works.

sandbox: https://gn3qm.csb.app/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked demo, `Component2` renders at `https://gn3qm.csb.app/component2` but when `goto nested level 2` is clicked, URL becomes `https://gn3qm.csb.app/component3` which means that `Component2` cannot render. As `Component2` cannot render, obviously any nested routes cannot be rendered.

Since `Component3` is nested inside `Component2`, path to `Component3` should be appended to the path to `Component2` so that when you click the `Link` component to render `Component3`, URL should be:

```
https://gn3qm.csb.app/component2/component3
```

You need to make following changes in `Component2`

- Change the value of `to` prop of `Link` component

  ```
  <Link to="/component2/component3">goto nested level 2</Link>
  ```
- Change value of `path` prop of `Route` component

  ```
  <Route path="/component2/component3" component={Component3} />
  ```

Instead of manually writing the path to `Component2`, you could use `match` prop from react router. You can get the current path using `props.match.path` and append `/component3` to the current path.

```
<div>
  <h1>Component2</h1>
  <Link to={`${props.match.path}/component3`}>goto nested level 2</Link>
  <hr />
  <Route path={`${props.match.path}/component3`} component={Component3} />
</div>
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit inspiring-buck-46gb3]

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  function Component3() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component3</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  function Component2() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Component2</h1>
        <Link to="/component2/component3">goto nested level 2</Link>
        <hr />
        <Route path="/component2/component3" component={Component3} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Component1</h1>
      <Link to="/component2">goto nested level 1</Link>
      <hr />
      <Route path="/component2" component={Component2} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

thanks